# Append a function at the end of another

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to add the function like following. 
My case is i will get a map, which has fields to filter data on google data store. I need it as query.filter().filter()..... Based on the map size.
Here is the code; I don't understand how to append another filter at the end based on size of filter

```
public List<T> listByProperty(Map<String,String> map)
{
    Query<U> query = ofy().load().type(entityObjectifyRootClass);

    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry :map.entrySet()) {
        //here i need to append filter(entry.getKey(),ventry.getValue())method to query
        // like query.filter("SDAf","sdf").filter("ert","erw").......
    }   

    //query.filter(propName, propValue).;
    return asList(query.fetch());
}
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append any function to another function as you wanted.

In your case
the below statement is working because load is returning an object that has a method called type.

```
ofy().load().type(entityObjectifyRootClass);
```

Where as the filter class just adds the filter property to the given query object, and it doesn't return anything. Hence you cannot do that.

So, one way to solve what you wanted is to use something like this.

```
query.filter("SDAf","sdf")
query.filter("ert","erw")
```